# How to add Javascript in Blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I'm trying to make a checkbox which, when clicked, shows (make visible) a text, and when unclicked hides a text, but the JavaScript doesn't work and I don't know if I'm correct or not. The HTML code is (div with id="acepto" is the one that should be hidden and shown):

```
<div class="required checkbox">
     <div class="checker" id="uniform-customer_privacy">
        <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="casilla" required  name="customer_privacy" autocomplete="off" onclick="mostrar()">
        <label for="newsletter-input"><a href="https://portugaletearkunautak.blogspot.com/p/proteccion-de-datos.html">Acepto política de Privacidad y Protección de Datos</a></label>
     </div>
</div>
  
&nbsp;</span></p><p><br/></p>

<div id="texto">
  <p><span style="font-size: large;">Poniéndote en contacto con nosotros aceptas la política de privacidad y protección de datos.</span></p>
</div>
```

I've inserted this piece of script in the `<HEAD>` of the theme (Theme > Edit HTML), but it doesn't work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
  //<![CDATA[function mostrar(){
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("casilla");
  var text = document.getElementById("texto");

  if (checkBox.checked){
text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
  }
  //]]>
</script>
```

I really appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you inserting that script code? Above `</head>`? Above `</body>`? Because it matters where it's placed, speacially on Blogger...

Comment: @OsvaldoCorreia it's above </head>, between <head> and </head>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not add // (double slash) in your code cause that will make comment text after it. a sample is given here and my case it worked.

```js
 
      function mostrar() {
         var checkBox = document.getElementById("casilla");
         var text = document.getElementById("texto");

         if (checkBox.checked) {
            text.style.display = "block";
         } else {
            text.style.display = "none";
         }
      }
```

```html
<div class="required checkbox">
      <div class="checker" id="uniform-customer_privacy">
         <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="casilla" required name="customer_privacy" autocomplete="off"
            onchange="mostrar()">
         <label for="newsletter-input"><a
               href="https://portugaletearkunautak.blogspot.com/p/proteccion-de-datos.html">Acepto política de
               Privacidad y Protección de Datos</a></label>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div id="texto" style="display: none;">
      <p><span style="font-size: large;">Poniéndote en contacto con nosotros aceptas la política de privacidad y
            protección de datos.</span></p>
   </div>
```

Comment: it did work! Thank you so much!

Comment: I just edit to check "Run code snippet". You should add the JavaScript in "script" tag while editing blog post in HTML mode. This is true for. Blogger.com

Answer (score 0):

There were several errors in your HTML, also using unneeded span elements. See the code here. Should help!

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById("casilla");
const text = document.getElementById("texto");

checkbox.addEventListener('change', monstrar);

function monstrar() {
    if (checkbox.checked){ 
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="required checkbox">
  <div class="checker" id="uniform-customer_privacy">
    <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="casilla" required name="customer_privacy" autocomplete="off" />
    <label for="newsletter-input">
      <a href="https://portugaletearkunautak.blogspot.com/p/proteccion-de-datos.html">Acepto política de Privacidad y Protección de Datos</a>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<br />

<div id="texto" style="display: none;">
  <p style="font-size: large;">
    Poniéndote en contacto con nosotros aceptas la política de privacidad y protección de datos.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! yes but the most important is how to run js in blogger, because it doesn't work :( (not the code, I mean the js in blogger). Thanks.